# How to get list of currently displayed rows in richfaces data table

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

Suppose i have 100 records and i am using pagination to display 10 items per page. If user sorts any column, displayed rows will change. How can i find which 10 rows are being displayed ?
I am using richfaces 3.3.1 and JSF 1.2.

Comment: Where exactly do you need this information?

Comment: I am using spring web flow for navigation and spring container for managing beans. If i get this information in backing bean, i would be able to use it in web flow scope.

Comment: So, you need this information in an action method of the backing bean which is invoked by an `UICommand` component?

Comment: Datascroller has an attribute scrollerListener which can be used to track pagination event. rich:column does not have any support for adding a listener for sorting event.

Comment: I implemented custom sorting in rich:datatable for tracking displayed rows.